# How to create a camera in 2D android game?

Tags: android

I want to create a game that look like callus95 games. Simply using 2D graphics drawn in paint. So the camera gonna look at hero from his side and I have a background that bigger than the screen, when hero moves the **background should slide back with enemy on it. Also I want to add zoom in and zoom out too**. Things that I tried:

1. I tried to used canvas.translate(x,y); but I think there should be a better way like create a real camera.
2. I found something like this to overload a camera but it' look like I have to use OpenGL if I'm not wrong.

> glOrtho( 0, 800, 0, 480, -1, 1 );

Am I really have to use OpenGL for a 2D game?

If anyone can tell me what should I use to have a camera object that would be great. Thank you for giving time.

Comment: Obligatory "use AndEngine" comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use gluLookAt function.

Comment: Currently I'm using canvas to draw everything when I'm using gluLookAt I think I have to change everything it that right?

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time about that camera: I'm writing that for peoples that will check this question in the feature. So if you are working on 2D game and using **canvas** for drawing your bitmaps keep using it and don't try to create a camera like in DirectX or OpenGL. Also you can use cavas.translate(x,y); for simulation of camera. For peoples that did't write much code. I suggest you to use **GL10** A book named "**Beginning Android Games**" will help you for using it.